# How to grant editing permissions for editing shapefiles

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, editing, permission

A user in my company is trying to edit shapefiles on his machine via ArcMap. However, when he tries to start an editing session, he gets an error message saying no layers are editable and warnings saying each specific layer does not have permissions to edit. He also cannot export the shapefiles to new ones, nor can he create anything such as a shapefiles or geodatabases. The shapefiles he is trying to create are saved in his local drive, and he is using an ArcGIS standard license. I am able to edit the shapefiles on another machine.

I am not sure what he missing in order to edit or create anything.

Comment: This is a pure OS issue. Shapefile and file geodatabase access is via Windows permissions. Trouble-shooting this is more a Tech Support process.

Comment: The user is able to edit other files in his machine, so not sure why it is isolated to ArcMap.

Comment: Interactive troubleshooting is not a GIS SE strength. There is nothing ArcGIS-specific about permission assignment. Check to make sure the TEMP folder is writable.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1383451/how-do-you-set-windows-file-permissions-security-options-non-recursively